# OR operator in XPATH predicate

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML, part of it which I want to query is:

`<c14>06</c14>
 <c14 m='1' s='2'>01</c14>
 <c14 m='2'>01</c14>`

Is the following XPATH predicate correct to query the elements other than `m='2'` ones?

`( some $t in c14[not(@m) or @m=1]/text() satisfies fn:number($t) =01)`

It gives correct result, but I am not sure how, because that `or` in the predicate would have returned two nodes - `not(@m) and @m=1`. How did it apply `text()` on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text()` [node test](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-node-test) is performed once for each item selected by the previous [step](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-steps) -- `c14[not(@m) or @m=1]`.

See [this section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-dynamic-context) (italics mine):

> Certain language constructs, notably the path expression E1/E2 and the
>   predicate E1[E2], create a new focus for the evaluation of a
>   sub-expression. In these constructs, *E2 is evaluated once for each
>   item in the sequence that results from evaluating E1*. Each time E2 is
>   evaluated, it is evaluated with a different focus.